# ASP.NET MVC Redirect to same page after submit button is clicked

Tags: html, asp.net, database, redirect, form-submit

some friends and I have started a team project but we are stuck at this point. We made a function of the site to add comments under every post. The problem is that when submit is clicked it adds the comment but doesn't refresh the page which causes some problems. The author stays "anonymous" and when refresh button is clicked it shows an alert:

> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you wish to continue?

However, if we just type the URL again and click ENTER everything is good: the author shows up and the comment appears only once. So the only solution for us is to redirect to the same page. Here is the form:

```html
<div style="text-align: left">
  <div><i>Leave your comment</i>
  </div>
  <form method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" type="text" id="1" name="commentText" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
      </p>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" onclick="redirect" value="Add comment" class="btn btn-default" style="" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is how the comments are printed on the page:

```html
 <h3>Comments</h3> 
<br>
<div>
  @foreach (var comment in ViewBag.Comments) {
  <section class="row">
    <article class="post col-md-12">
      <div class="about">
        Posted on <i>@comment.Date</i>
        @if (comment.AuthorId != null) { @: by <i>@comment.Author.FullName</i>
        }else { @: by <i>anonymous</i>
        }
      </div>
      <div class="body">@comment.Text</div>
    </article>
  </section>
  }
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the best way to handle that is to send the data to the server via an Ajax call and refresh just the comment section with the response as opposed to reloading/redirecting to the same page.

Comment: Well, the data to the server is send via the controller and we use this type of sending everywhere in the application. I couldn't fully understand the second part of your answer. How can this be done.

Comment: That's fine. You could add Ajax functionality and still use "regular" controllers. You could also go the `ApiController` route if you wanted. How to do it would be better answered by a tutorial probably. A very simple starter would be [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx). You can get more in depth searching around; same is true for the web api route.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Ajax.BeginForm()` helper.

In the `AjaxOptions()`, you'll want to set the Httpmethod to "Post", InsertionMode.InsertBefore (or After depending on where you want new comments), and UpdateTargetId = "your-comment-div".

You'll need to include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js so the Ajax helper works correctly. You can use the nuget package manager to pull it in. Be sure to add it to your jquery bundle.

Then, you need to create the post action in your controller to accept the comment params and return a partial view.

Doing thIs keeps the Ajax confined to a razor helper and controller method.

View:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxAddComment",
                           "MyController", 
                           /* route params */, 
                           new AjaxOptions()
                           {
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
                               UpdateTargetId = "commentsDiv",
                               HttpMethod = "Post"
                           }, htmlAttributes: new { /* ... */ }))
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @* comment form... *@
        </div>
    }

   ...

    <div id="commentsDiv">
        <div class="comment">...</div>
        <div class="comment">...</div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<PartialView> AjaxAddComment(string comment, /*...other params*/)
{
    var newComment = ... // comment viewModel
    // add comment to db
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return PartialView("_CommentPartial", newComment);       
}
```

_CommentPartial:

```
<div class="comment">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to use javascript or c# method and add onclick event on the button submit? I made a research but none of the options worked for us. Maybe we did something wrong.

Comment: You could have a JavaScript onclick event with an Ajax call if you want. It's up to your preference. I just think the Ajax html helper reads better for this simple case.

Comment: Sooo with tried to with "formaction" event on the button. It redirects but doesn't help. I mean the author still stays "anonymous" until the page is reloaded. Maybe we'll try some of the solutions above. We are still beginners and it seems a little difficult for us but there's no other solution.